# what's the exact type of expression: addition of two value of type unsigned char

Tags: c, visual-c++

```
unsigned char c0=255,c1=1;
char c2=c0+c1;   //(1)
```

no any warning(/W4), and c2 is 0

```
int i=c0+c1;    //(2)
```

no any warning(/W4), and i is 256

what's the type for expression(c0+c1)? If unsigned char, why not 0 in (2). If int, why no warning in (1).

It seems relate to "Integer Promotion".

Help!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
unsigned char c0=255,c1=1;
char c2=c0+c1;
```

`c0 + c1` is of type `int` and it evaluates to `256`.   This `int` value is converted to `char` when it is assigned to `c2`. No warning is required, because you can always assign operands of any different arithmetic type. (Technically it is an initialization, but the same type and conversion constraints apply for assignment and initialization).

```
int i=c0+c1;
```

`c0 + c1` is still of type `int` and no conversion occurs during the assignment.

Comment: if type of (c0+c1) is int and its value is 256, the c2 will be 0. Because it is equivalent to following:
    char c2=(char)256;

Answer (score 0):

In case 1, the type is *unsigned char* because you have specified the type of c2 as unsigned char, while in case 2 the type is *int* because you have specified the type of i as int.

Comment: Does compiler infer the target type(type of expression) by the left side of assignment?

Does anyone have other opinion?